# QGIS plugin creating the Duplicates tool bars why?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, toolbar

I created a custom tool bar with QGIS plugin but when reload the plugin its creating another duplicate toolbar.
My code:

```
class TestToolbar:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'TestToolbar_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&TestToolbar')

        # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
        # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
        self.first_start = None
        
       
    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('TestToolbar', message)

    def add_action(
            self,
            icon_path,
            text,
            callback,
            enabled_flag=True,
            add_to_menu=True,
            add_to_toolbar=True,
            status_tip=None,
            whats_this=None,
            parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""
        # #print("excuting Inintgui")
        self.toolBar = self.iface.addToolBar("TestToolbar")
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("TestToolbar")

        self.DataLoader = QAction(
            QIcon(r":\plugins\TestToolbar\icon.png"),
            QCoreApplication.translate("IMPRESStoolbar", "Tool1"), self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.DataExport = QAction(
            QIcon(r":\python\plugins\TestToolbar\icon.png"),
            QCoreApplication.translate("IMPRESStoolbar", "Tool2"), self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.AddMapLayers = QAction(QIcon(
            r":\plugins\TestToolbar\icon.png"),
            QCoreApplication.translate("IMPRESStoolbar", "Tool3"), self.iface.mainWindow())

        self.toolBar.addAction(self.DataLoader)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.DataExport)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.AddMapLayers)

        self.DataLoader.triggered.connect(self.DataLoaderExecute)
        self.DataExport.triggered.connect(self.DataExportExecute)
        self.AddMapLayers.triggered.connect(self.AddMapLayersExecute)

    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&TestToolbar'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
    def DataLoaderExecute(self):
        print ("DataLoaderExecute")
    def DataExportExecute(self):
        print ("DataExportExecute")
    def AddMapLayersExecute(self):
        print("AddMapLayersExecute")
```

Why it's creating the duplicates? How can I rectify?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Within `unload` method, you must add  `del self.toolbar`.

```
def unload(self):
    """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
    for action in self.actions:
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(self.tr(u'&TestToolbar'), action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)

    del self.toolbar  # ADD THIS LINE
```